# PCs and printer are unable to communicate with each other even if they both can communicate with the router over wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, printer

both my printer and my PC are connect to the router (DLink DIR-605L) using WIFI and internet is working on my PC. My printer works only if I connect my PC to router over a ethernet cable but it doesn't if I detach the Ethernet cable. the firewall software (SPI) on my router is disabled. Does anyone have a idea why this is happening?

```
configurations:

PC: DHCP
Router: 192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0
Printer: 192.168.2.222/255.255.255.0
```

Comment: you're right. sorry for the typo.

Comment: If (with PC on WiFi) you do a tracert to the printer's IP, what are the results?

Comment: What 802.11 modes does each device support?

Comment: printer Operating Mode is 802.11b. PC supports Operating Mode   802.11n.

Comment: I doubt your router will support 802.11b unless you specifically configure it to. 802.11b is ancient and many wireless networks refuse to support it because it imposes costs on other devices.

Comment: the manual states "The DIR-605L is still fully compatible with the IEEE 802.11b and IEEE 802.11g standard". and printing works if I run a cable from my PC to the router (the printer connected to the router over wifi)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007:    tracert when cable is attached:      C:\Users\Zhicheng>tracert 192.168.2.222

Tracing route to BRW0080928E497B [192.168.2.222]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     3 ms     2 ms     3 ms  BRW0080928E497B [192.168.2.222]

Trace complete.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: tracert when cable is detached: C:\Users\Zhicheng>tracert 192.168.2.222

Tracing route to 192.168.2.222 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     2 ms     3 ms     3 ms  192.168.0.1
  2    11 ms    15 ms    27 ms  xe-1-0-0-55.ipr02.totftds.distributel.net [206.80.255.122]
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Comment: Please edit your question and put that information into it directly, and use the formatting tools so it's not just a pile of characters. ;)

Comment: You tracert appears to show that your gateway is on a different subnet than the printer and PC. Please edit your question to include the IP configuration of all three devices (IP, subnet mask, gateway).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: I updated the post with device configurations

Comment: Tell us the PC is "DHCP" doesn't help, we need to know what IP/Mask and Gateway are assigned by DHCP (and therefore being used by the PC). It'll help if you provide both set of settings assigned by DHCP when on Wired and wireless. Also, why is your router on a different subnet than your printer? Do you have a routing rule in place to route data between those subnets?

Comment: It's working now after I put the printer in the same subnet as the router's (Change its IP to 192.168.0.222). thanks to all. special thanks to 'TECHIE007.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22035/discussion-between-user2723438-and-c007).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the router may be configured to only allow a 802.11b connection when it won't impact any other devices connected (which is when the only other connected devices are 802.11b, or there are no other devices connected).

Is it possible to get an ethernet cable to the printer?

You could probably configure the router to allow 802.11b to run actively all the time, but it will cost you performance (probably significantly).